# Multiple options for purchase in VirtueMart

Tags: system, payment, cart, virtuemart

I want to use virtue mart for online shopping system on a joomla website. But I wonder if it supports multiple purchase options like;

Add to Cart (will added into the cart)
Download Online (customer will be able to download the files like .pdf or .mp3)
Get physical product (product will be shipped to the customers address, or can visit the head-office and get it by hand, etc)

The Payment methods would be like;

Online payment (via credit card, online banking, paypal, master card, visa card, etc)
Other Means (via bank, western union, within the country options, or can visit the head-office and pay it by hand, etc)

Please, guide me if it is possible, and if yes, then a brief detail on HOW?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Using Virtue-mart you can achieve all your requirement easily.

You can get following options with VM

1. Add to cart options
2. Call us For details
3. Download files with external plugins
4. Shipping options to physical address
5. Payment with all major credit cards
6. even more.

By default VM have Following Payment options

1. Paypal
2. Authorize.net
3. System Pay
4. Payzen
5. even more you can find on the plugin [Store](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-payment-systems)

For your shipping option you will get shipping plugin from VM Team

1. UPS(Paid)
2. USPS(Paid)
3. FEDEX(Paid)
4. You can create custom methods(For warehouse pickup).

For online file download you can get many plugins [like](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/extension-specific/virtuemart-extensions/virtuemart-shipping/23503)

Hope this will make a clear idea about VM.

If you are planning for huge Virtual store (more than 1000 of item VM is Good for you it have lot of additional features.)
for small stores better to go for Wordpress & WooCommecrce(Simple and Easy)